# why changes in network access permission of user object affects userParameters attribute

Tags: active-directory

if enable allow access of network access permission in dial in tab m:  d is added in userparameter.

what is the relationship between Dial in Tab and userparameters attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh564280.aspx

The Terminal Service settings are also related to userparameters attribute, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff635189.aspx

Comment: i cannot understand the unicode string userparameter for user previlege and callback number.

Comment: I suggest you set the value in the ADUC page and check the change in the userParameters attribute.